# Custom domain email will only work with gmail

Tags: email, gmail

I've setup a mail server using [this tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/ubuntu-18-04-iredmail-email-server) (it uses iRedMail). Everything seemed to work, since I am able to send emails to my regular gmail account (it does arrive in the spam folder).

However, I can't send emails to my hotmail email adress, it never arrives. I've also tried sending an email to [this tester](https://www.mail-tester.com/) but the website never received it.

I also checked that port 25 is opened using:`telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25` and it is opened.

Those are the errors I get in POSTFIX's logs:

```
May  5 10:00:35 mail postfix/smtp[34561]: 49GFj34Jfyz7VK: to=<test-jlo5knrfx@srv1.mail-tester.com>, relay=none, delay=46572, delays=46542/0.03/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to reception.mail-tester.com[94$
May  5 10:05:05 mail postfix/qmgr[2322]: 49G6074WMbz7Tq: from=<information@tensor.fr>, size=1911, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  5 10:05:05 mail postfix/qmgr[2322]: 49G62g3t1Nz7Tv: from=<information@tensor.fr>, size=1758, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  5 10:05:35 mail postfix/smtp[34683]: connect to mail.oriwijn.com[45.55.104.203]:25: Connection timed out
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Doesn't your MTA logs any error or queue up mails when they don't arrive to the receiver?

Comment: Good call, I didn't know those existed :D I've updated my post with the errors I get.

Comment: Did you follow "Step 9: Improving Email Deliverablity"? Especially Hotmail is very strict in blocking unknown email servers...

Comment: Yes, I've followed those steps, I've added a PTR Record and a DKIM record, which was over 16hours ago, so they should have updated worldwide by now.

Comment: Which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. For some reason, my ISP only allows its own smtp server and gmail's smtp. It's Orange in France.

My fix was to use their smtp server as a relay.